# C# - Split CSV File by Removing Bad Rows

Tags: c#, .net, csv

I have a csv file with 2 million rows and file size of 2 GB. But due to a couple of free text form columns, these contain redundant CRLF and cause the file to not load in the SQL Server table. I get an error that the last column does not end with ".

I have the following code, but it gives an OutOfMemoryException when reading from fileName. The line is:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
```

How can I fix it? Ideally, I would like to split the file into two good and bad rows. Or delete rows that do not end with "CRLF.

```
int goodRow = 0;
int badRow = 0;
String badRowFileName = fileName.Substring(0, fileName.Length - 4) + "BadRow.csv";
String goodRowFileName = fileName.Substring(0, fileName.Length - 4) + "GoodRow.csv";
var charGood = "\"\"";
String lineOut = string.Empty;

String str = string.Empty;
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

StringBuilder sbGood = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sbBad = new StringBuilder();

foreach (string line in lines)
{
     if (line.Contains(charGood))
    {
        goodRow++;
        sbGood.AppendLine(line);
    }
    else
    {
        badRow++;
        sbBad.AppendLine(line);
    }
}

if (badRow > 0)
{
    File.WriteAllText(badRowFileName, sbBad.ToString());
}
if (goodRow > 0)
{
    File.WriteAllText(goodRowFileName, sbGood.ToString());
}

sbGood.Clear();
sbBad.Clear();

msg = msg + "Good Rows - " + goodRow.ToString() + " Bad Rows - " + badRow.ToString() + " Done.";
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [TextFieldParser Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: To start do not use File.ReadAllLines, but File.ReadLines. Read the docs to understand the fundamental difference.

Comment: Also, don't use `WriteAllText` and `AppendLine`, rather write the lines to the files in the loop immediately. Alternatively, consider using some GNU command line tools to split the file.

Comment: Please do not use `File.ReadAllLines` because that is causing the exception since it tries to read all the content at once. I might suggest to use this excellent OOS library: https://www.filehelpers.net/

Comment: Change `ReallAllLines` to just `ReadLines` and see if it works any better. The latter only holds the one line in memory at a time. Additionally, use `StreamWriter` objects for the good and bad files instead of `StringBuilder`, so you don't try to keep the entire contents in memory.

Comment: [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) is able to read record with CRLF if wrapped inside pair of `"`. So no bad line at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not suggest reading the entire file into memory, then processing the file, then writing all modified contents out to the new file.

Instead using file streams:

```
        using (var rdr = new StreamReader(fileName))
        using (var wrtrGood = new StreamWriter(goodRowFileName))
        using (var wrtrBad = new StreamWriter(badRowFileName))
        {
            string line = null;
            while ((line = rdr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Contains(charGood))
                {
                    goodRow++;
                    wrtr.WriteLine(line);
                }
                else
                {
                    badRow++;
                    wrtrBad.WriteLine(line);
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: I forgot the ReadLines() function.   That's a better solution than using the StreamReader (just in terms of cleaner code) as demonstrated in @joel-coehoorn 's answer.  I recommend his code over mine.

Comment: I used StreamReader but just added a line to add header row to good row file. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can translate that code like this to be **much** more efficient:

```
int goodRow = 0, badRow = 0;
String badRowFileName = fileName.Substring(0, fileName.Length - 4) + "BadRow.csv";
String goodRowFileName = fileName.Substring(0, fileName.Length - 4) + "GoodRow.csv";

var charGood = "\"\"";

using (var lines = File.ReadLines(fileName))
using (var swGood = new StreamWriter(goodRowFileName))
using (var swBad = new StreamWriter(badRowFileName))
{    
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        if (line.Contains(charGood))
        {
            goodRow++;
            swGood.WriteLine(line);
        }
        else
        {
            badRow++;
            swBad.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}

msg += $"Good Rows: {goodRow,9}   Bad Rows: {badRow,9} Done.";
```

But I'd also look at using a **real csv parser** for this. There are plenty on NuGet. That might even let you clean up the data on the fly.